# SQL Server Service Stuck in ‘Starting’ Status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not able to connect to the database engine. I have recently installed SQL Server 2012 after formatting my hard drive.

Operating system : Win 7 Enterprise 64-bit

When I try to connect to the database engine :

1. `WN7X64-XXXXXXX`, I get the following error message

   > A network-related or instance-specific error occured. Could not open connection to the SQL Server'.
2. I tried accessing using `(localhost)`. It did not work.
3. I tried accessing using `(localhost)/SQLExpress`. It did not work.
4. I tried accessing using `(localhost)/MSSQLServer`. It did not work.
5. I tried accessing using `MSSQLServer`. It did not work.

When I checked the services. SQL Server status is starting, and it does not give me the option to start/stop.  SQL Server Agent status is blank, when I start the service it gives

> Error 1068 : dependency service or group failed to start.

```
Name                                                  Status       Startup Type
SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)    Started      Automatic
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)                              Starting     Automatic
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)                                     Automatic
SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)            Started      Automatic
SQL Server Browser                                    Started      Automatic
SQL Server Distributed Replay Client                  Started      Automatic
SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller              Started      Automatic
SQL Server Integration Services 11.0                  Started      Automatic
SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)           Started      Automatic
SQL Server VSS Writer                                 Started      Automatic
```

Comment: Sql 2013 ? when it launch

Comment: typo error. It is SQL 2012.

Comment: Please, look at the Windows Event Log, there might be something there the tells you the reason why MSSQLSERVER service do not start.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes get SQL Server Express stuck in 'starting', in fact, just now, which is why I googled up this page.  The solution is to kill the process and restart it.

Simplest way to do that is through Task Manager, which you can start by right clicking the Windows system tray (banner at the bottom of the screen where minised programs go).  Processes tab, Sort processes by Name, find all beginning 'SQL...' and stop them.

To restart SQL Server right click the Windows Start button, start Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Services, scroll to all services starting 'SQL...', right click to refresh, and stop any that are running, then start the 'SQL Server' service, followed by any others that are set to Auto or Manual start.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and MSDN Documentation did not help. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307288.

It was to do with that there was an orphan Sql related service i.e SqlWriter was hanging around. Go to task manager and killed it. Then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a SQL Server default instance (not Express), you can use:

- just a `.` (dot)
- just a `(local)`   (be aware: **in round brackets**)
- just a `localhost`    (be aware: **NO** brackets)

See the [official MSDN documentation on `Logging In to SQL Server`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188642.aspx) for more details and explanations, and for even more options how to connect.

Comment: ** SQL Server Service Stuck in ‘Starting’ Status **                                       1. Open a command window by pressing windows key + R
2. Type “sc queryex MSSQLSERVER” to get basic info about this service
3. Identify the PID of this MSSQLSERVER service
4. Type “taskkill /f /pid [pid_number]” to terminate the hung process
5. Type “net start MSSQLSERVER” to restart the servic

Comment: @SKP: reboot and possibly reinstall - something is screwed up

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost or (local). Not (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . go to task manager , search for "SQL Server Windows NT" then end the task . after that , go to your services (Run services.msc) and restart your sql server instance .

Solution works for me in MSSQL Server express edition with Windows 10 environment .